# Cannot find function FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl in object [object Object]

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets-api

How add data from google spreadsheet to firebase?

When I add library FirebaseApp in Google spreadsheet script but it gives error as  "Cannot find function getDatabaseByUrl in object".

I follow the following step:
  1. file>Project Properties>(copy the project key)>save
  2. Resources>libraries>(paste the project key inside find project key text)>search
  3. select version>give identifier name(like "FirebaseApp")

```
    function writeDataToFirebase() {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var dataToImport = {};
      for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var Sr_No=data[i][0];;
        var Employee_Id=data[i][1];                                                     
        dataToImport[Sr_No + '-' + Employee_Id] = {
          NAME:data[i][3],
          DESIGNATION:data[i][4],
          BL_Start_Date:data[i][5],
          Start_Date_at_Company:data[i][6],
          End_DATE:data[i][7],
          Mobile:data[i][8],
          PAN_CARD_NO:data[i][9],
          Email_Address:data[i][10],
          DOB:data[i][11]   
        };
      }
    //  Logger.log(Firebase);
      var firebaseUrl = "https://fundoohr.firebaseio.com";
      var secret="tzRgYNHu26ZkeJLbP7n2DlVBuogeB9NgSrF9z7a2";
      var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl,secret);
      base.setData("", dataToImport);
    }
```

Comment: The [App type in the Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App) does not have a `getDatabaseByUrl()` method. What library is it that you're using?

Comment: you are attrmpting to use a clientside library from serverside.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the firebase library first.

See this link how to install it: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase